# How to take a text file line by line as the input of the gpt2's generate method and save its output to another text file?

Tags: python, readline, large-language-model, gpt-2, text-generation

I want to generate text using gpt2 after fine-tunning and I want to use a text file as the input for the generate function of the model however not reading it as a one text block but line by line.

At the beginning I have tried this code:

```
text_data = open('/content/drive/My Drive/output_data.txt', 'w')
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/input_data.txt') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        ids = tokenizer.encode(f'{line}',add_special_tokens = True, return_tensors='pt')
        final_outputs = model.generate(
             ids,
             do_sample=True,
             max_new_tokens=ids.shape[1]+1,
             pad_token_id=model.config.eos_token_id,
             top_k=50,
             top_p=0.95,
             num_return_sequences=1
         )
         a = tokenizer.decode(final_outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
         text_data.write(a)
text_data.close()
```

However instead of looping on input_data.txt lines and processing it line by line, it takes it as a whole text and takes a long time running at this line

```
final_outputs = model.generate(
             ids,
             do_sample=True,
             max_new_tokens=ids.shape[1]+1,
             pad_token_id=model.config.eos_token_id,
             top_k=50,
             top_p=0.95,
             num_return_sequences=1
         )
```

And at the end in the output file, I found only the result of one line of the input_text file.

I have tried many idea but it gives the same result:

- like reading the input_text separately using readlines() and using another loop on these lines to generate the output.
- I also tried to convert the input.txt to csv form and read it as a dataframe and looping on it.

Any suggestion it will help. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the code is getting expected results... you should set the mode in open() to "a" (append) instead of "w" (write) in `text_data` output. That's why you are getting just one line in output file.

Comment: `text_data.write(a)` does not write `a` as a line. If your output file is just one line, it is because to get separate lines it should be `text_data.write(a + '\n)`  to get separate lines. That said I would check your input file for End of line (EOL) characters. There may not be any.